# Wordpress says .htaccess file is unwriteable, but it's definitely writeable

Tags: apache, wordpress, .htaccess

I've just finished moving a Wordpress site to a new server. The domain has not changed, nor has the directory that Wordpress is installed in; the only thing that has changed is the machine it happens to be on.

The only problem I seem to have had as a result is that my permalinks aren't working, and when I go into the permalink settings, it claims that my .htaccess is unwrittable. For testing sake my .htaccess is currently CHMOD777, so it definitely is.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The permalinks themselves aren't working, i.e. the rules already in the .htaccess file from the previous server aren't taking effect. Mod rewrite, header and expire weren't installed.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced problems in changing file permissions through FTP sometimes; CPanel always works. So try doing it from your host's control panel.

If that doesn't work, try editing .htaccess file manually. Follow [this link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Creating_and_editing_.28.htaccess.29) to learn how to.

Your files may be 'owned' by a different user, especially if your hosting provider moved the files for you or if you used a script. If you continue to have problems, ask your hosting provider to check if the owner and permissions are set correctly on the files.

Comment: Hi Sawant, it's a dedicated server so no CPanel available. As it turns out I hadn't installed all of the require Apache modules. Thanks for the help.